# SPWebCollection.Add gives exception "That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers."

Tags: spwebcollection

I created an assembly for SharePoint 2010, which is deployed into the GAC.
It contains SPWebCollection.Add method. When the "STS#1" is used as template, there is no exception, the site is created successfully.

```
newSite = subSites.Add(siteUrl, siteTitle, siteDescription, 1033, "STS#1", true, false);
```

However when I use a custom site template, there is an error:
"That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers."

```
newSite = subSites.Add(siteUrl, siteTitle, siteDescription, 1033, WorkspaceTemplate, true, false);
```

As this is a shared/hosted environment, it's not allowed to change the trustlevel.

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,
Andre

Comment: Can you add a Workspace from the UI?

Comment: Yes, I can create from UI. Also from PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Is your code dll signed? and can you also check if your AssemblyInfo.cs has

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()]
```

If above doesn't help then try to change the trust level from “Minimal trust” to “Medium trust” or other higher level. More info: http://www.ben-morris.com/allow-partially-trusted-callers-asp-net-shared-hosting-environments

Comment: As this is a hosted environment, it is not allowed to change this trust level in the web.config. APTC has also been added.

Answer (score -2):

You can set your web application to run in a medium trust environment, by adding the following line to your web.config file:

`<trust level=”Medium”/>`

Try this and it should work.

Comment: As this is a hosted environment, it is not allowed to change this trust level in the web.config.